# React-Router Navigation Appearing Twice On path='/'

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

In the application the navigation appears single in all the pages except the home which is `'/'`.

How do I prevent the navigation from appearing twice in the home. Here is a screenshot and the code for the react-router.

Screen Shot OF Double Menu In React-Router:
[image]

Here is the code:

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return ( 
     <BrowserRouter>
        <div>
            <Navigator />
            <Switch>
                <Route path='/'exact strict component ={HomeIndex} />
                <Route path='/Pricing' exact component ={Pricing} />
                <Route component={Error404}/>
            </Switch>
        </div>
     </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: try removing the `strict` prop

Comment: @c-chavez I removed it but nothing happens after that..

Comment: could you show us your `HomeIndex` component code?

Comment: @c-chavez https://codeshare.io/GLbnJl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once check your `HomeIndex` component, may be you are using `<Navigator />` again inside `HomeIndex` component.

Comment: it's okay. @BoringProgrammer